# Importing a Laravel Project's Mysql Database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, laravel, phpmyadmin

I'm migrating my Laravel project to another computer. Project files have been migrated but i have some issues on migrating the database.

**I exported my database through phpmyadmin** (windows 7, xampp version 7.3.0) and imported to the new computer (ubuntu, xampp version 7.3.2-0).

**When i try to import the .sql file, i get this error:**

```
Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

    Missing expression. (near "ON" at position 25)

SQL query: Edit Edit

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON;

MySQL said: Documentation
#2006 - MySQL server has gone away
```

I tried to inspect what is the matter and checked the file but on 25th line there is nothing but straight comment line like so:

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------
```

Besides that, there is also a warning below error, which is pretty long so i'll share only part of it.

```
Warning in ./libraries/classes/Dbi/DbiMysqli.php#213
Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=7892

Backtrace

./libraries/classes/Dbi/DbiMysqli.php#213: mysqli_query(
,
string 'INSERT INTO `items` (`id`, `title`, `type`, `alternative`, `description_html`, `view_count`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `thumbnail`, `file`) VALUES (3, \'test book 3\', \'book\', \'someurl.com\', \'<b>cool2</b>\', 0, \'2019-01-07 18:41:33\', \'2019-01-07 18:41:33\',
```

And bunch of numbers.

**Any help or idea is appreciated. Thank you**

What i've tried so far:

-Tried to disable "foreign key check" and it didn't help.

-Tried to run .sql file content through phpmyadmin sql tab. Pasted the sql queries. Got almost the same error :"SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON"

-Tried to import data and structure separately, got a different error. "max_allowed_package_size". So i did increase the size from 1mb to 10 mb to match the size. Worked.

-Then i did import the original export file after increasing max package size. Worked like charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Tried to import data and structure separately, got a different error. "max_allowed_package_size". So i did increase the size from 1mb to 10 mb to match the size. Worked.*

*Then i did import the original export file after increasing max package size. Worked like charm.*

**Conclusion: problem was about max allowed package size. Increased it through conf file.**